# NHibernate doesn't remove unuseful record when update child collections

Tags: nhibernate, cascade

When I use Nhibernate 3 to update children, the removed item in children doesn't delete from databse.

Case describe below

```
class Parent {
   string Id;
   string Name;
   IList Children;
}
class Child {
   int ChildId;
   string Name;
   string Value;
   Parent parent;
}
```

hdm Mapping file shows below 
Parent.hdm.xml

```
<bag name="Children" table="ClientsExt" inverse ="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
  <key column="ChildId"/>
  <one-to-many class="XXXX.Child, XXX"/>
</bag>
```

Child.hdm.xml

```
<many-to-one name="Parent" column="Id" class="XXXX.Parent, XXX" not-null="true"/>
```

Let's suppose there is existing parent which associates a set of children  in database

```
Parent Table
Id = "P1", Name = "Test"
Child Table
ChildId = 1, Id="P1", Name = "N1", Value = "V1"
ChildId = 2, Id="P1",Name = "N1", Value = "V2"
ChildId = 3, Id="P1",Name = "N2", Value = "V3"
```

In my case, I need to update children partially. 
In the updated Parent need to update the record 2
set value of ChildId = 2, to value = "NEWVALUE"
and **remove** ChildId = 1, Id="P1", Name = "N1", Value = "V1"
and ChildId 3 will be keep.

so I get the Parent from database firstly,

```
var entity = _parentRepo.getById("P1");

var children = entity.Children;

var updatedChildren = children.ToList<Child>;

var tmpList = new List<Child>();

//biz means the business logic object which contains update info

if (biz.N1.Count > 0){

     var existN1 = children.Where(x=>x.Name.Equals("N1")).Select(y=>y.ChildId);

     int count = existN1.Count;

     int index = 0;

     biz.N1.ForEach(x=>{

         if(index < count){
            tmpList.Add(new Child(){ Id = existN1[index],Name="N1",Value="newValue",Parent = entity });
         }else{
           tmpList.Add(new Child(){ Name="N1",Value="newValue",Parent = entity });
         }
     });

  updatedChildren.RemoveAll(x=>x.Name.Equals("N1"));

  updateChildren.AddRange(tmpList);
}

entity.Children = updateChildren;
//Save the entity
```

However, in Database, the record 2 update the value to "NEWVALUE", but didn't remove the ChildId = 1, Id="P1", Name = "N1", Value = "V1" . 
Why?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the last few code, then life come to easy.   `entity.Children.Clear(); updateChildren.ForEach(x=>entity.Children.Add(x)`

Answer (score 1):

What happend, is that the above code has broken the *session* principle, splitted the chain. Whenever we want NHibernate to do wise decisions, we must to keep its hands on the underlying stuff - all the time. And this is not in accordance:

```
var children = entity.Children;
var updatedChildren = children.ToList<Child>; // a brand new NHibernate-detached coll
...
// operations out of the scope of the NHiberante session
...
entity.Children = updateChildren; // broken chain of information
```

Behind the scene, NHibernates places its own smart Collection into the `entity.Children` property. It is tracking information about changes *(removed elements, changed..)* so if it is asked to persist changes... NHibernate knows...

If we put brand new, disconnected collection, NHibernate can hardly find out, that there is some element missing. No way how to issue DELETE.

**Solution:** work with the `entity.Children` reference all the time. Then we'll get what we need...

Comment: Cool, so much thanks. Now I change the code, and it works. thanks a million.

Comment: Great to see that. Enjoy NHibernate, amazing tool ;)